# Can I / How can I force JBoss & Eclipse to use only one core?

Tags: eclipse, jboss, cpu-cores

I'm currently running a couple instances of Eclipse -- one has a JBoss server which is hosting a site which I'm testing and the other contains other projects/code which I'm working on.

My machine is dual core (AMD Atholn II X2 B24 with 4GB of RAM).

I would like to have one instance running on one core and have the other instance running on the other, so that they don't "interfere" with one another.

Is this even possible?  If so, are there any guides/tutorials/directions that you can point me to?

Comment: Windows 7, 32-bit.  Why install a 32-bit OS on 64-bit hardware is a question to ask the company I work for :-P

Comment: You safe memory (a 32bit prozess has a smaller overhead of RAM consumption), but you can only use ~3,5GB of it.

Comment: Less than 8GB RAM are to little for a development system, with a IDE and jboss running.

Comment: If you don't mind doing it manually you can go in to task manager / processes, right-click one of the Eclipses and "Set Affinity" and select which CPUs you want it to use.

Comment: Awesome @PaulCager!  I think you should add this as an answer as well!

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the JBoss Server using sysinternals psexec.

I've been using `psexec` to limit the cores on which an application runs, but I'm not sure if it will work in conjunction with Eclipse/JBoss/Java.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Using `psexec`, you can limit the the processor core using the `-a` parameter.

```
psexec -a 1 c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

will run notepad on core 1.

```
psexec -a 2 c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

will run it on core 2.

Comment: Once psexec is running in the command line, do you have to leave the prompt open until you are finished with the program?

Comment: If you run it with the `-d` option, you can close the prompt window.